# How To Query A VB.NET Datasource

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have added a Datasoruce to my current project and the following has been added to my App.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings.dbConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db.accdb"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

How can I now query and update this datasource?

I have the following query:

```
Dim sqlstr As String = "INSERT INTO Accounts(Username,Password)VALUES('" & Trim(Account(0)) & "','" & Trim(Account(1)) & "')"
```

But am not too sure how to actually run the query (New to VB, used to PHP and a single database connection file!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I now query and update this datasource?

***NOT* how you're doing it right now!**

You have two **huge** problems with that code:

1. NEVER use string concatenation to insert values into an sql statement like that.
2. NEVER store a password as plain text in a database.

There are ZERO cases where either of those are ever acceptable.

Here's one way it might look instead:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Account (UserName, PasswordHash) VALUES ( ? , ? )"
Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnectionString").ConnectionString), _
      cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("UserName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Account(0).ToString().Trim()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PasswordHash", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = HashPassword(Account(1).ToString().Trim())

    cn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Notice that I changed the name of one of your columns, and that I referrenced a HashPassword() function that doesn't exist yet.  You'll need to build your own HashPassword() function to go with that code. When building the function, look for an scrypt or bcrypt function to use. Do not use MD5. The best that .Net has built in is SHA1. If you really *must* go that route (SHA1) you can, but scrypt or bcrypt are greatly preferred (this is why I'm not providing the function for you: it will rely on other code you must first get from the web).

When you go to authenticate a user, you must then use the same function to hash the attempted password, and compare the hashes rather than the original passwords. This is the only safe way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The software itself connects to my server to authenticate the user, a simple app I am making while learning VB. Before the data is sent to the server it is MD5 encrypted to compare with the password in my online database (Also MD5 encrypted).

Got it all working after a little while, was having issues with type mismatches and changed OleDbType.Char to OleDbType.Integer on an additonal entry for the database.

Also, what does the , 50 / , 20 have to do with the insert statement? Is it a limitation to the characters being inserted?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The 50 and 20 are guesses for how large the columns are, and should be changed to match the actual columns.  You should **NOT** use md5 to hash your passwords. It is easily crackable.  Also, hash != encryption.

Comment: What is "dbConnectionString" here?

Comment: @MdAshrafulIslam It' s the name of the connection string as listed in the web.config file.

Comment: @JoelCoehoom Oh! I am using it with Windows Application. Altough I have solved my problem in a different way. Thank you